How to slide in page from left to right in Compose?
How can I do this in Jetpack Compose, where when the user clicks on an item in the list, the screen slides in from the right, displays data and closes on a left-to-right swipe?
Does this happen by navigating to a new screen, or animating a composable?
I need logic or simple code on how this works.


Yes you can use slide transition for this. You can use this basic idea to implement the same on click of item to display details screen by sliding in from left and back again.
class SlideTransitionExample : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApp()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(navController, startDestination = "screen1") {
        composable(
            route = "screen1",
            enterTransition = {
                when (initialState.destination.route) {
                    "screen2" ->
                        slideIntoContainer(
                            SlideDirection.Left,
                            animationSpec = tween(700)
                        )
                    else -> null
                }
            },
            exitTransition = {
                when (targetState.destination.route) {
                    "screen2" ->
                        slideOutOfContainer(
                            SlideDirection.Left,
                            animationSpec = tween(700)
                        )
                    else -> null
                }
            },
            popEnterTransition = {
                when (initialState.destination.route) {
                    "screen2" ->
                        slideIntoContainer(
                            SlideDirection.Right,
                            animationSpec = tween(700)
                        )
                    else -> null
                }
            },
            popExitTransition = {
                when (targetState.destination.route) {
                    "screen2" ->
                        slideOutOfContainer(
                            SlideDirection.Right,
                            animationSpec = tween(700)
                        )
                    else -> null
                }
            }
        ) {
            Screen1(navController)
        }

        composable(
            route = "screen2",
            enterTransition = {
                when (initialState.destination.route) {
                    "screen1" ->
                        slideIntoContainer(
                            SlideDirection.Left,
                            animationSpec = tween(700)
                        )
                    else -> null
                }
            },
            exitTransition = {
                when (targetState.destination.route) {
                    "screen1" ->
                        slideOutOfContainer(
                            SlideDirection.Left,
                            animationSpec = tween(700)
                        )
                    else -> null
                }
            },
            popEnterTransition = {
                when (initialState.destination.route) {
                    "screen1" ->
                        slideIntoContainer(
                            SlideDirection.Right,
                            animationSpec = tween(700)
                        )
                    else -> null
                }
            },
            popExitTransition = {
                when (targetState.destination.route) {
                    "screen1" ->
                        slideOutOfContainer(
                            SlideDirection.Right,
                            animationSpec = tween(700)
                        )
                    else -> null
                }
            }
        ) {
            Screen2(navController)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Screen1(navController: NavHostController) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text("This is Screen 1")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("screen2") }) {
            Text("Go to Screen 2")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Screen2(navController: NavHostController) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text("This is Screen 2")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Button(onClick = { navController.popBackStack() }) {
            Text("Go Back to Screen 1")
        }
    }
}

The sample has two screens and a button in each of them. Clicking on button would navigate and pop screens. Each enter, exit and pop are animated based on the destination routes.

Thank you, it works. How could I implement a left-to-right swipe to close screen2?

use the slideleft direction to pop screen 2

you can also refer this https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/animation/quick-guide and check for Animate whilst navigating to different destinations heading content this will give you an idea of how to animate when navigating between composables

composable(route = Screen.HomeScreen.route,
        enterTransition = {
            slideInHorizontally(
                initialOffsetX = { 1000 },
                animationSpec = tween(500)
            )
        },
        exitTransition = {
            slideOutHorizontally(
                targetOffsetX = { -1000 },
                animationSpec = tween(500)
            )
        },
        popEnterTransition = {
            slideInHorizontally(
                initialOffsetX = { -1000 },
                animationSpec = tween(500)
            )
        },
        popExitTransition = {
            slideOutHorizontally(
                targetOffsetX = { 1000 },
                animationSpec = tween(500)
            )
        }
    ) {
        HomeScreen(navController)
    }

Just add the transitions to your composable if you don't want them in the entire app screens. If you want them in the whole app, then add transitions inside the navhost graph.
